Predicate logic: Find a model so that the formula is false.
This question comes from an old exam: Describe a model where the following is false: $\forall_{x} \forall_{y}(P(x,y) \to \neg Q(x,y))$.
I take the model $M$ as follows:
$\begin{align}
M = ( \!U = \text{the set of even numbers},
    &  \quad P(x, y) = "\!2 \text{ divides } x \text{ and } y\!", \\
    &  \quad Q(x, y) = "\!x \times y \text{ is divisible by } 2\!\end{align}$
My question: Does this satisfy the requirement? I think so but I am always unsure about these. I have posted a similar question yesterday but I am not sure whether or not this counts as a double post because it is a little bit different and also this time I want to verify. If this is not allowed, notify me and I will delete it.

That strikes me as a "too easy" question. You can give the structure where U contains a single element x (for whatever value of x you like), and P(x, x) and Q(x, x) are both true. Of course, if it specified "a model of arithmetic" or some such, then it's closer to being a real question, but even then, P and Q have no special meaning within the axioms of arithmetic, and can still be defined e.g. as tautologies.

Proving that a formula $A$ is false in a certain structure (aka model, according to your terminology) amounts to proving that its negation $\lnot A$ is true in such a structure.
In your case, we have $A = 
\forall x \forall y \, (P(x,y) \to \lnot Q(x,y))$.
Its negation is $\lnot A = \lnot \forall x \forall y \, (P(x,y) \to \lnot Q(x,y)) \equiv \exists x \exists y \, (P(x,y) \land  Q(x,y))$, where $\equiv$ stands for logical equivalence, obtained by applying de Morgan's laws.
Thus, within the structure you have defined, your question amounts to showing that there exist two even natural numbers $m$ and $n$ that are both divisible by $2$, and such that $m \times n$ is divisible by $2$. Of course, this is true! Take for instance $m = n = 2$.
Said differently, your answer is correct.

In general, for this kind of question, I always prefer to turn the sentence to the positive, that is, if I have to prove that a formula is false (in a certain structure) I show that its negation is true (in the same structure), and I internalize the negation as much as I can. This way, I avoid dealing with nested negations, which are very error-prone.
